# Statistics; density functions and likelihood estimators

Tags: statistics, functions, maximum-likelihood

[I dont get a single bit of this, the question is nothing like things I've done before.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLgbj.png)

Comment: This site is not a HW-factory. You do not even ask a question.

Comment: Can you explain three individual things about the question which you don't understand?

Comment: Look at your notes, talk to your fellow students, talk to your instructor, then cycle back and do it again.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a Pareto distribution with a scale factor of $1$ and a shape parameter $\theta$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution)

The maximum likelihood estimate of the shape parameter (in the case of $1$ for the scale parameter):
$$\overline{\theta}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\ln{(X_i)}}.$$
You can substitute your data...

As far as the last question. The inverse of the maximum likelihood estimate is the average of the logarithms of the data:
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\ln{(X_i)}.$$
In order to see if this is unbiased we have to compute the mean:
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nE[\ln{(X_i)}]=E[\ln(X_1)]=\theta\int_1^{\infty}\ln(x)x^{-(\theta+1)}\ dx.$$
Integrate by part with $u'=x^{-(\theta+1)}$ and $v=\ln(x)$ and you will learn if the average above is biased or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

To help you get started,

Write down the  log-likelihood function, $$\ln \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\theta}{x_i^{\theta+1}}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \ln \left( \frac{\theta}{x_i^{\theta+1}}\right)=n\ln \theta-(\theta+1)\sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i$$

To find $\hat{\theta}_{ML}$, differentiate the previous expression with respect to $\theta$ and equate them to zero and solve for $\theta$.